# Content appears before jQuery dropdown animation is complete

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown

I'm using jQuery to slidedown and reveal content on my page after a "read more" link is clicked. The animation works well but the content that is being revealed appears immediately after the link is clicked, before the animated slidedown. The funny part is that I've used this code on a few other sites and never had this issue.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ShowHide(){
$(".details").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 500 });
}

</script>
```

and the html

```
<div class="readmore"><a href="#" onclick="ShowHide(); return false;">More Info</a></div>            
    <div class="details">
        <div class="description">
         <div class="title">Description</div>
          <p>content here</p>

         <div class="title">Subscribe</div>
         <a href="#">lorem</a><br />
         <a href="#">lorem</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any help would be great! Also on a side note, I may want to have multiple instances of this slidedown on one page. Right now clicking the "read more" link would reveal all the "details" divs. How would I go about making this work just on a single div without having to write new code for each instance. An example where I would want that would be a wordpress site that reveals details from a post in a list of posts.

Comment: seems to work fine... http://jsfiddle.net/Vhwdw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the `div` containing the content (in your case the one with the class "details") also has the `overflow: hidden` CSS style set.

To answer your second question, you could do it as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    //Bind the ShowHide function to onclick for each first link in the "readmore" div
    $('div.readmore > a').click(ShowHide);
});

function ShowHide(event)
{
    //Find the next "details" div sibling below the link container and animate it
    $(event.target).parent('div.readmore').next('div.details').animate(
        {"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 500 });
}
```

Also make sure to remove the inline "onclick" handler assigned to the link when using this.

Comment: overflow: hidden is applied and it's still creating the same issue. Also when I replace my JS with the JS above the 'read more" button doesn't do anything.

Comment: Fixed the overflow issue (there was a typo in my css...sigh) but this JS still isn't working for me.

Comment: @Clayton C: D'oh, the click event binding didn't work as I expected - I've now corrected the binding and tested it via jsfiddle.net. It should work now :)

Comment: @ClaytonC: Not sure if you got my last comment - if you did, does my revised code work for you?